# Background image cutting off at bottom on very large screen displays

Tags: html, css

Here is a codepen of my code: https://codepen.io/kloba1004/pen/rNezLVj

```
body::before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url(https://wallpaperset.com/w/full/1/6/8/155013.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

You can see my problem here: http://responsivetesttool.com/ , for example at a size of 5120x2880.

I have searched a lot, but can't apply suggested solutions online or they don't work because of some conflicting styles probably.

PS. I am just a newbie and have been coding for 10 days, the first time in my life.

Comment: Hi, from which size, do you have a problem ?, your link responsivetesttool.com is not helping because we dont have the url to test.

Comment: Sorry, just now I understood what u wrote. For example issue appears at 5120x2880

Comment: This is the white part under your image that you are concern about ?

Comment: @MaxiGui Yes, exactly.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see under hte image is not part of your website.

As you can see on the top, I am by 5120 x 2880 resolution (which is over big like a TV).

If you check in the details, of the inspection developer tool, as I did, you can notice that your `html` size is about 2064px and stop there. You can see the limit of your html page in blue on my screen.

If you would apply a css like `html {height: 100%}`, you would see that your html would takt the whole height of this space generated by codepen.io

So the rest you see under as white is just generated by the iframe of codepen.io to try to adapt the content of heir website.

[image]